# Open excel file "protected with password" ask for password - Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, console-application, excel-interop

I developed a C# console application (using Framework.NET 4.0 and Excel interop) which queries specific data from a ms-access database and create a Excel file ".xlsx".

The generated Excel file is protected with password.

The following code is used for create a new Excel file *"protected with password"*:

```
myWorkbook.Password = "xxx";
myWorkbook.SaveAs(path_file);
myWorkbook.Close();
myExcel.Quit();

releaseObject(myWorkbook);
releaseObject(myNewSheet);
releaseObject(myExcel);
```

I use the following code for open the generated Excel file:

```
Workbook myExcelWorkbooks = myExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename: Path.GetFullPath(file_to_excel_file),
                                                      ReadOnly: false,
                                                      Password: "xxx");
```

With the previous code, there is no need for user enter the password and allows the application continues its work *(i.e the Excel file isn't shown when console application is running)*.

I tested the previous code in PC's with Windows 7-10 Operating System and Microsoft Excel 2010-2016 and it works.

However, when I execute my console application in a PC with Excel 2007 and Windows 7 OS, Excel program opens and ask to user enter the password.

**How can change such behavior?**, why in the PC with Excel 2007 the opened Excel file is shown and requires the user enter the password?